# Homeline plug-on neutral breaker installation

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I'm looking to add a plug-on neutral combination AFCI/GFCI breaker for a new circuit. Can this be installed over the neutral bus if a different circuit already has a neutral screwed in to that part of the neutral bar, or do I need to move the existing neutral wires first?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The [instructions](https://download.schneider-electric.com/files?p_enDocType=Instruction+sheet&p_File_Name=48840-249-01.pdf&p_Doc_Ref=48840-249-01) for a Homeline plug-on neutral breaker indicate that the plug-on neutral clips land in the “empty” spaces on the neutral bar between the pairs of screws, so it should not be necessary to move any existing neutral/ground wires that are on the bars.